# How to avoid an infinite loop trying to show a php start page with php + jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, smarty

I've been working on a web page with php + smarty +  jquery + html.

I need to display the different content of a web page using the window.location = mainPAge.php instead of $("#div-Page").show()

In other projects I make a simple switch like this:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize{
       showPage("none");
}

function showPage(page){
       switch (page) {
        case "none":
            $("#mainDiv").show();
            $("#webDiv2").hide();
            $("#webDiv3").hide()
            break;
        case "opcion2":
            $("#mainDiv").hide();
            $("#webDiv2").show();
            $("#webDiv3").hide();
            break;
        case "opcion3":
            $("#mainDiv").hide();
            $("#webDiv2").hide();
            $("#webDiv3").show();
            break;
}
```

And it work perfectly, but now I can't use this, I need to use the pages from php directly so I use this:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize{
       showPage("none");
}

function showPage(page) {
    switch (page) {
        case "none":
            window.location = "mainContent.php";
            break;
        case "opcion2":
            window.location = "secondContent.php";
            break;
    }
```

The problem !!! It seems that when I mix jQuery "$(document).ready(initialize)" with "window.location = 'mainContent.php'" the browser goes into an infinite loop.

I really don't know why and less how to avoid the loop. If I don't try to show mainContent.php at the beginning of the page, and I assign a button to show the mainContent.php, that way work perfectly.

But I need to display mainContent.php for automatic way to start page.

I appreciate so much your suggestions.

Regards !!!!

Comment: What triggers the change in page?  Where do you call showPage('option2')?

Comment: When you use `window.location = ...` you redirect to a new page. Once this new page opens, I assume the same code is run again causing another reload. Look into AJAX and how you can download data from another page and insert it into the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine for me, whether I do showPage("none") or showPage("option2").  Perhaps you have an issue with the script in the page that is being loaded?

```
$(document).ready(initialize());

function initialize() {
        showPage("none");
        //showPage("option2"); // Or this
}

function showPage(page) {
    switch (page) {
        case "none":
            window.location = "test1.php";
            break;
        case "option2":
            window.location = "test2.php";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Benjamin I forgot say something, I use too smarty php plugin so when i call mainContent.php this one makes an                                           $smarty -> display("mainContent.tpl") besides other things, so that is the end of the invokes.